# Why is the audio coming out of my Turtle Beach headset really quiet?

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, drivers, microphone

I have a Turtle Beach headset that I usually use with my PS4. The mic works perfectly loud on PS4. When plugging it into my computer I connect it to the pink slot at the back of the computer. Once it’s connected I try and record my voice — I have tried online, Audacity, Adobe Audition and many other ways — I have even tried listening to the device via Windows 10.

I am on Windows 10, I think it’s a VIA headset or it said something like that in the device manager. The issue is its really quiet and you can’t hear it at all.

When putting the boost up to 30 (max) you can hear it a little.

Volume is also max at 100. Is there a better way of doing this?

I have tried so many things, restarting, connecting it in and out, trying other microphones, uninstalling and reinstalling the drivers, updating the drivers, so many but nothing works?

Comment: Ok you plugged it into the pink plug? But not also the green one? Pink is for the microphone, green is for headphones. Also, analog headphones do not show up in device manager. Are your headphones perhaps USB? These are important questions the answers to which change everything about how to fix your problem.

Trying to piece together what you've said... it sounds like your headset uses USB for the headphones but still uses analog for the mic... kinda weird.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your speaker icon in the lower right corner, near your clock and choose “Playback Devices.”

Scroll down the list under the “Playback” tab to your Turtle Beach headset, right click and choose “Properties.”

Go to the “Enhancements” tab and click the box that says “Loudness Equalization.”

Careful, it may be loud as soon as you hit “Apply.”